# VirtualLock and stack variables

Tags: c, windows, locking, virtual-memory

I have a C DLL that declares a a large buffer on the stack (about 4K) among other variables. To try to prevent the buffer from being written to the paging file I VirtualLock it.  For example:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MyCall(...)
{
    UCHAR bigBuffer[4096];
    int vlocked = 0;
    ...
    vlocked = VirtualLock(bigBuffer,sizeof(bigBuffer));
    ... do stuff ...
    if (vlocked)
    {
        VirtualUnlock(bigBuffer,sizeof(bigBuffer));
    }
    ...
    return (0);
}
```

Firstly, is this ill advised? For example, can this cause problems with the stack?

Secondly, will it have the desired effect of preventing writing to paging file?

Thanks.

Comment: `VirtualLock()` will keep the page in physical memory, but it does not mean that it will not write that page in secondary storage. OS can write the page on disk, without purging it from physical memory. Don't think you can achieve your goal from user mode program.

Comment: The Internet is the worst possible place to get security advice.  This code will work just fine, you cannot get a warranty.  It is overkill, just scrubbing the buffer by overwriting it content after usage is the normal approach.

Comment: Thanks, I do scrub the buffer as well (before unlocking it). But can this technique cause any sort of stack leak? Do I need to make sure the buffer is on a boundary? The VirtualLock documentation makes no mention of an alignment requirement.